# Failed to connect to target PowerShell

Tags: exchange, microsoft-office-365, office365

When I try mgration my Exchange server to office 365 via codtow office 365 mgration tool connection target server When I put information Global administrator 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZ6EY.png)

How can i fix this error ?

Comment: CodeTwo provides technical support with the purchase of their products. You should be reaching out to them for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is documented [here](https://www.codetwo.com/userguide/out-of-office-manager/verification-powershell.htm).

This issue occurs if either an internal firewall or the Windows Remote Management service has not been started.

**Start WinRM:**

1. Open services.msc
2. In the Services window, double-click Windows Remote Management.
3. Set the startup type to Manual, and then click OK.
4. Right-click the service, and then click Start.

Comment: Thank you for answering me ,But i do this steps problem not fix

Start WinRM:

Open services.msc
In the Services window, double-click Windows Remote Management.
Set the startup type to Manual, and then click OK.
Right-click the service, and then click Start.

internal firewall is runing

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the impact of Exchange Online side. You could first try to connect to Exchange Online Powershell under common method. More details please review the link below. If it still fails, please provide error info screenshot. When it is successful, it might be a codtwo software problem, as what joeqwerty said, contact the cod two SE for further analyzing.

**Connect to Exchange Online PowerShell**

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/exchange-online/connect-to-exchange-online-powershell/connect-to-exchange-online-powershell?view=exchange-ps